# About Derivative.

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

What is derivative of $\sin\sqrt x$ using the definition of the derivative ?

The definition of derivative is:-

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Comment: Are you allowed to use Taylor series?

Comment: This is kind of unmotivated.  Is this a homework problem?  What have you tried?

Comment: Really? First principles? Why? Why would **anyone** want to do that, to himself or to his students? Really...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629163/how-to-find-derivative-of-sin-sqrtx-using-difference-quotient

Comment: Not a good exercise because you have to use the same steps used for proving the chain rule.

Comment: **got it**  here [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629163/how-to-find-derivative-of-sin-sqrtx-using-difference-quotient)